# How to get existing record on a unique key violation

Tags: db2, unique-constraint, rowid

when performing an insert I get the following error message

```
AN INSERTED OR UPDATED VALUE IS INVALID BECAUSE INDEX IN INDEX SPACE xxxxx CONSTRAINS 
COLUMNS OF THE TABLE SO NO TWO ROWS CAN CONTAIN DUPLICATE VALUES IN THOSE COLUMNS. 
RID OF EXISTING ROW IS X'0000000A20'.. SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, DRIVER=3.53.95
```

How can I do a select to get the row that already exists in the database?

Platform is z/OS; `SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` returns `DSN09015` so I guess thats Version 9

Comment: can you be more specific, or post your code you use here?

Comment: What information do you need? In the quoted error message an RID is mentiond: X'0000000A20' In oracle I can do something like select * from <table_name> where rowid = '0000000A20' and get the existing row in the database. I'm looking for the equivalent for DB2.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the platform that DB2 is running on (z/OS?) and the version of DB2.  The syntax (and whether it's even possible) will depend on this information

Comment: ... I'd check the index for the constraint it has, then use the columns listed to `SELECT` the row.  If it's complaining to you about violating a unique constraint, you should have the necessary information to retrieve the row.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde added information about the platform. Not sure about the version, will add that information tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

`X'0000000A20'` is Hexadecimal format. You can translate it with Windows calc.

```
A20 = 2592
```

So you can do `SELECT * FROM table_name where RID(table_name) = 2592` and you will get what you need

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the utility DSN1PRNT which helps you to read db2 zos data-pages in native format (even data are compressed). Read the SYSPRINT and find your Datas.

Keep in mind that the RID is an address in this file : X'PPPPPPPPII'

If the RID is: X'0000000A20' then the page number is X'0000000A' and the Id of the row ix x'20' (x'20' is 32 decimal ==> 32th row in the page) 
find the address of the 32th row with the ID-MAP table in SYSPRINT and enjoy your datas.